# Objective C especial Epoch format to Date

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the number of the day in the year (Epoch format) 2015,

65 = 06/03/2015, I want to find the correct way to get the date, I saw several examples with the interval from 1970, but in my case I have only the interval in the year.

Even I want to control the problems with the leap year, because the year will change, I will get from the current year.

Example in Java:

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Integer.parseInt(dayNumber));
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));

            Date date = calendar.getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat formatJobDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
            jobDate = formatJobDate.format(date);
```

Comment: Look at `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar`.

Comment: You can use NSDateComponents & NSCalendar, but I'd just create a format for NSDateFormat, using standard [formatting codes](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).  Eg, put your date in a string as "65 2015" and parse into an NSDate with date format `@"D yyyy"`.  (Then, of course, format the NSDate however you like.)